# Using Raphael JS, partially fill a circle

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm trying to fill a portion of a circle with a colour. For example, having a circle with 2/3 red and 1/3 empty.

The Raphael JS documentation doesn't help much. What is the best way to approach this?

Some examples can be seen at below picture:

[image]

```
var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('shape_container'), 400, 100);
var circle = paper.circle(50, 50, 30);
circle.attr (
        {
            fill: '#F00'
        }
    );
```

With the code above, I can draw a circle with full of red..
I could not find any way for how to fill 2/3 red..

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please try reading our [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). This question is a little incomplete. What exactly have you tried? *Why* can't you do what you would like?

Comment: I tried to add a screenshot but it didnt let me cauz im a new member. Anyway, I can draw rectangle or circle and I can fill them with what color I want. But the thing is I want to fill specific percentage, lets say 3/8, of a shape. Also I'm new at raphael, I tried to read raphael references but still I have no idea how to do that.. I hope my problem is more clarified now.

Comment: Right, I've edited your question to be a little more clear. You still ought to attach some kind of code to show us what you've tried; the research you've done.

Comment: thanks for your editing, I added some example and a piece of code..

Comment: Looks kind of like you could use a charting plugin.  Have you tried http://g.raphaeljs.com?  Documentation is garbage and it's hard to understand but short of that, getting what you want with pure Raphael is going to be tough.

Comment: I also tried g.raphael, I could draw piechart, but still not able to do what i want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome, Alperen.  I believe what you actually want is an arc path rather than a circle.  Take a look at this:

```
function arcpath( canvas, x, y, r, ratio )
{
    if ( ratio >= 1.0 ) return canvas.circle( x, y, r );
    var degrees = 360 * ratio;  //  we use this to determine whether to use the large-sweep-flag or not
    var radians = ( Math.PI * 2 * ratio ) - Math.PI / 2;    //  this is actually the angle of the terminal point on the circle's circumference -- up is Math.PI / 2, so we need to subtract that out.
    var pathparts = 
    [
        "M" + x + "," + y,
        "v" + ( 0 - r ),
        "A" + r + "," + r + " " + degrees + " " + ( degrees >= 180 ? "1" : "0" ) + " 1 " + ( x + ( r * Math.cos( radians ) ) ) + "," + ( y + ( r * Math.sin( radians ) ) ),
        "z"
    ];

    return canvas.path( pathparts );
}

var partial_circle = arcpath( canvas, 250, 350, 100, 0.75 ).attr( { fill: mapit_red, stroke: mapit_black } );
```

The geometry in the arcpath function is reasonably straightforward (though I had to look up the reference for [large-sweep-flag](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands), which was decidedly non-obvious).  I'm sure this could be optimized substantially, but it's a functional first step.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a RaphaelJS custom attribute for this very purpose. It can be animated, so you can control the rotation/size of the slice and create donut or partial donut shapes too.

```
paper.customAttributes.filledArc = function(e,t,n,r,i,s){var o=360;if(o==i){i-=.001}i+=s;var u=(90-s)*Math.PI/180,a=e+n*Math.cos(u),f=t-n*Math.sin(u),l=e+(n-r)*Math.cos(u),c=t-(n-r)*Math.sin(u);var h=(90-i)*Math.PI/180,p=e+n*Math.cos(h),d=t-n*Math.sin(h),v=e+(n-r)*Math.cos(h),m=t-(n-r)*Math.sin(h);return{path:[["M",l,c],["L",a,f],["A",n,n,0,+(i>180+s),1,p,d],["L",v,m],["A",n-r,n-r,1,+(i>180+s),0,l,c]]}}
```

And then:

```
paper.path().attr( {
    filledArc: [x,y,radius,width,degrees,rotation]
    fill: mapit_red,
    stroke: mapit_black
} );
```